# Make ListView FindItemWithText search anywhere in text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, search

```
Dim query as String = "Card" ' Just an example, I would call this with a function
Dim itemF As ListViewItem = ListView1.FindItemWithText(query, False, 0, True)
If (itemF IsNot Nothing) Then
    itemF.Selected = True
Else
    Alert("Nothing was found")
End If
```

So I am trying to use this code to add a search functionality. The problem is, this works if I'm trying to go from the beginning to the end. But if I wanted to search `Card` and find `W_Card_Brt_Better`, I won't get expected results. Though if I search, `W_Card`, the item will be selected.

Comment: what do you mean "if I wanted to search `Card` and find `W_Card_Brt_Better`" is Card a search term? your use of code markup makes it confusing. From Object Browser, *Finds the first ListViewItem ... that* **begins** *with the specified text value*.  If you want to do a `Contains` type search you will have to iterate, LV just does a `StartsWith`

Comment: Say you're searching for the word "Card" but something is prefixed before it. I want it to show the result anyways. In this scenario it searches from the beginning. Not anywhere in the text. I'm not sure how to describe it :/

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.FindItemWithText` always searches using BeginsWith pattern - this is by design, as specified in the docs:

- [ListView.FindItemWithText Method (String) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3h4x385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Finds the first ListViewItem that begins with the specified text value.

If you are trying to do anything more custom than that, I suggest you search against the underlying data source instead. You should generally avoid performing any kind of business logic/validation from the UI control directly.

In the business object, you can do a simple for loop, or build a dictionary, to make it search faster, and encapsulate this search functionality within a method or property, which you will call from the UI layer.

Answer (score 0):

`FindItemWithText` finds the first ListViewItem ... that **begins** with the specified text value.  If you are looking for Items/SubItems which simply CONTAINS the text you have to iterate and search yourself.

To make it like FindItemWithText, specify a start point and Bool for the SubItem search:

```
Function FindItemContainingText(lv As ListView, searchSubs As Boolean,
               StartIndex As Integer,
               searchTarget As String) As ListViewItem

    If (StartIndex >= lv.Items.Count) Or (StartIndex < 0) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim FindMe As String = searchTarget.ToLowerInvariant
    Dim subStopper As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = StartIndex To lv.Items.Count - 1
        If searchSubs Then
            subStopper = lv.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
        Else
            ' Item.Text/Label can be read from SubItem(0)
            ' just look at it if not searching subI's
            subStopper = 0
        End If

        For n As Integer = 0 To subStopper
           If lv.Items(i).SubItems(n).Text.ToLowerInvariant.Contains(FindMe) Then
                ' return the LVI that contains the text
                Return lv.Items(i)
            End If
        Next n

    Next
    ' note!
    Return Nothing
End Function
```